# Making a base url without /public

Tags: server, nginx, apache

I'm creating a site that works now at www.mysite.com/public/

I would love to get to drop the /public off the url so it is:

www.mysite.com

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a Craft question as a web server question.

The directory structure of Craft is intended for the web server to have the public (or web in Craft 3) directory configured as the document root.

This is a configuration setting you’ll find in your Apache, Nginx or other web server documentation.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I just had to move my files. Thanks for your help.